# Shorten length of key in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck at trying to shorten the keys of my dictionary.

This is `d1`:

```
{
    'A0Z40': [ 'A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166' ],
    'A0Z41': [ 'A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411' ],
    'A0Z42': [ 'A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046' ],
    'A0Z43': [ 'A1101' ]
}
```

And I'm trying to get this:

```
{
    'A0Z' : [ 'A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166' ],  
            [ 'A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411' ], 
            [ 'A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046' ],   
            ['A1101']
}
```

I've tried with a dictionary comprehension

```
d = {k[:3] : v for k, v in d.items() }
```

but it erased the value since a dictionary can only have unique keys...

Do you have any other solution?

Thank you very much

Comment: your expected output is not valid dict. Maybe you want the value to be list of lists? Or combine all lists in single list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with regular `for` loop using `get` and default value

```
d = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    d[k[:3]] = d.get(k[:3], []) + v
```

this will combine the lists in the values to one list under the key `'A0Z'`

```
{'A0Z': ['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166', 'A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411', 'A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046', 'A1101']}
```

If you would like to have the value as a list of lists just put the value `v` in a list in each iteration

```
d[k[:3]] = d.get(k[:3], []) + [v]
```

outout:

```
{'A0Z': [['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166'], ['A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411'], ['A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046'], ['A1101']]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output is not valid dict. Maybe you want the value to be list of lists? Or combine all lists in single list?

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'A0Z40': ['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166'],
  'A0Z41': ['A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411'],
  'A0Z42': ['A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046'],
  'A0Z43': ['A1101']}

result =  defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data.items():
    result[key[:3]].extend(value) # or .append(value)

print(result)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A0Z': ['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166', 'A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411', 'A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046', 'A1101']})
```

or when using `.append()`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A0Z': [['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166'], ['A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411'], ['A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046'], ['A1101']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
D = {'A0Z40': ['A14160,A14161,A14162,A14163,A14164,A14165,A14166'],
     'A0Z41': ['A1403,A1407,A1408,A1409,A1410,A1411'],
     'A0Z42': ['A1201,A1205', 'A12041,A12042,A12043,A12044,A12045,A12046'],
     'A0Z43': ['A1101']}

# to merge this lists you could do this
ML = []
for v in D.values():
    ML += v
ND = {'A0Z': ML}
print(ND)
# if you want a list of lists you could do this
ML = []
for v in D.values():
    ML.append(v)
ND = {'A0Z': ML}
print(ND)
```